# data mungling in python-pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data which something looks like this:

```
   UserID        region1      region 2          region 3       Conditionid
0       0            NaN        NaN             NaN            NAN
1     693              2          1             NaN            NAN
2     709              1        NaN             NaN            100
3     730            NaN        NaN             NaN            NAN
4     840            NaN        NaN              5             100
```

Here numbers in the region columns represent the number of visits.

Now I want to calculate a metric A such that among users who have visited that region , what percentage have a particular condition with conditionid equal to 10. So this has to done for each column(region). 
A simple logic for one one region would be such as :

```
if region 1 != NA and conditionid=100 then count=count +1`.
```

Once I have this count, then I have to divide this by visits for region1. So firstly we have to iterate in first column row wise and then in second column(region2) again row wise and so on for all the regions. Now problem is how to iterate in the manner mentioned above and how do I store the metric A for each region ? I think there is some built-in mechanics in pandas-but not sure.

Comment: You should modify the title of your question to be a little more specific. Something like "conditional arithmatic on a dataframe" maybe

Comment: I believe that comes under the general topic of data mungling only. You would like to share any thoughts on the approach that should be adopted to tackle the problem?

Comment: generally speaking you don't want to iterate through a dataframe. look into the `apply` method: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html. Also, the point of stackoverflow is to be a resource for future readers who might have a similar question. There are currently over 7100 pandas questions. Your title, as it current reads, will not at all help future readers understand what the topic of this question is.

Answer (score 0):

When using pandas, you should not iterate through rows. Nearly every problem you will face can be solved using boolean logic and/or vectorized operations.

```
d = {'UserID' : [0, 693, 709, 730, 840],
 'Region1' : [np.nan, 2, 1, np.nan, np.nan],
 'Region2' : [np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
 'Region3' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5],
 'Conditionid' : [np.nan, np.nan, 100, np.nan, 100]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

You can then apply some boolean logic to find the count which you're interested in:

```
df[~(df['Region1'].isnull()) & (df['Conditionid'] == 100)]['Region1'].count()
```

Note, the `~` means NOT true. So, in this case, Is NOT isnull.

If you want to iterate through specific columns, you can do something like this:

```
from __future__ import division
for i in range(1, 4):
    column = 'Region' + str(i)
    print column
    numerator = df[~(df[column].isnull()) & (df['Conditionid'] == 100)][column].count()
    denominator = df[~df[column].isnull()][column].count()
    print numerator / denominator
```

This will create 'Region1' to 'Region3', and sum up what I think you're looking for. If not, this should at-least give you a good starting point.